Unable to write Spark Streaming data from Kafka
I am trying to write Spark Streaming data fed from Kafka locally as csv. The data folder shows blank.
The Folder Structure is added in the screen shot.

I am adding the Kafka Producer code as follows
import json
import random
import time

from confluent_kafka import SerializingProducer
from datetime import datetime

from faker import Faker


fake = Faker()


def generate_sales():
    user = fake.simple_profile()

    return {
        "transaction_id": fake.uuid4(),
        "user_name": user["username"],
        "email": fake.email(),
        "product_id": random.choice(["product1, product2, product3, product4", "product5", "product6"]),
        "product_category": random.choice(["Electronic", "Grocery", "Fashion", "metal works", "sports", "Cosmetics"]),
        "price": round(random.uniform(1, 10000), 2),
        "quantity": random.randint(1, 1000),
        "productBrand": random.choice(["apple", "Nestle", "Tanishq", "Hokkins", "Nike", "Lakma"]),
        "currency": random.choice(["INR", "USD", "EUR", "GBP"]),
        "transactionDate": datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
        "paymentMethod": random.choice(["Payment Gateway", "Bank Transfer", "Cash", "Credit Card", "Debit Card"])
    }


def delivery_report(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print(f"Message delivery failed with error {err}")
    else:
        print(f"Message delivered to topic: {msg.topic} and partition: {msg.partition()}")


def produce_sales_kafka():
    topic = 'sales_financial_report'
    config = {
        'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092'
    }
    producer = SerializingProducer(
        conf=config
    )

    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        try:
            transactions = generate_sales()
            transactions['totalAmount'] = round(transactions['price'] * transactions['quantity'], 2)

            print(f'The Total Transaction amount is {transactions["totalAmount"]}')
            print("The Json Value",json.dumps(transactions))
            producer.produce(
                topic=topic,
                key=transactions['transaction_id'],
                value=json.dumps(transactions),
                on_delivery=delivery_report
            )

            producer.poll(0)
            count += 1
            time.sleep(1)

        except Exception as e:
            print('The Error encountered is', e)


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Generating sales transactions...\n")
    produce_sales_kafka()


And the Kafka Consumer & spark Streaming code is as follows:
import os

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, from_json, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, FloatType, IntegerType

# Define the schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("transaction_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("user_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("email", StringType(), True),
    StructField("product_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("product_category", StringType(), True),
    StructField("price", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("quantity", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("productBrand", StringType(), True),
    StructField("currency", StringType(), True),
    StructField("transactionDate", StringType(), True),
    StructField("paymentMethod", StringType(), True),
    StructField("totalAmount", FloatType(), True)
])


def get_spark_context():
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Streaming from Kafka") \
        .config("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown", True) \
        .config('spark.jars', './jars/kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar,./jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.0.jar') \
        .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 4) \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .getOrCreate()
    print('Spark session created', spark)
    return spark


def connect_kafka():
    spark = get_spark_context()
    print("-- Connecting to Kafka --")
    df = (spark
          .readStream
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
          .option("subscribe", "sales_financial_report")
          .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
          .load()
          .select(from_json(col('value').cast('string'), schema).alias('sales_transactions'))
          .select(col('*'))
          )

    df.printSchema()
    if df is not None:
        query = df.writeStream \
            .format("csv") \
            .option("path", "data/") \
            .option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint/") \
            .outputMode("append") \
            .queryName("Finance sales") \
            .start()

        query.awaitTermination()

    else:
        print("---")


I tried to change the code query, even though error is not provided but can't see the files in the mentioned directory.

Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python?Rust?JavaScript? forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

print query status, register a callback, what's the error message?

@Kashyap meaning?
